# Solution for finding if range of rows have consequtive months- add a row with missing month

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to be able to check if range of rows has consecutive months and if any is missing add a row with the missing month (format of Month/1/2020 works). As seen in image below February is missing.
I assume i could use a while loop mixed with if statements but not sure how to write VBA code for it. please advise. thanks!

[image]

Comment: If you try, it's a call for help. If you don't it's a request to do the work for you.

Comment: Have you any experience in VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this :

[image]

From the example above, the inserted row will be :
1. 2 rows above G2 where the value is Aug and Sep 
2. 2 rows above G5 where the value is Jan and Feb
3. 1 row above G10 where the value is Aug
4. 1 row above G14 where the value is Jan
end so on.

So, the result is like this :
[image]

The code is:

```
Sub test()
Set rng1 = Range("G1") 'change if needed
Set rng2 = rng1.Offset(1, 0)

Do
CellMonth = Format(rng1, "m") 'the month in the "current" cell
If CellMonth <> "12" Then 'if the month in the "current" cell is not 12
CheckMonth = Format(DateAdd("m", 1, rng1), "m") 'then check month is the next month
Else
CheckMonth = "1" 'else, check month is 1
End If
NextCellMonth = Format(rng2, "m") 'the month in the next row

If NextCellMonth <> CheckMonth Then 'if the month in the next row is not the next month of "current" cell
n = NextCellMonth - CheckMonth 'get the discrepancy
For i = 1 To n 'loop as many as the discrepancy value
rng2.EntireRow.Insert 'insert entire row
oFill = Format(DateAdd("m", 1, rng1), "m") & "/01/20" 'prepare the value for the newly created row
rng2.Offset(-1, 0).Value = oFill 'fill the newly created value
'rng2.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.Color = vbYellow
Set rng1 = rng1.Offset(1, 0)
Set rng2 = rng1.Offset(1, 0)
Next i
End If

Set rng1 = rng1.Offset(1, 0)
Set rng2 = rng1.Offset(1, 0)
Loop Until rng2.Value = ""
End Sub
```

The day and the year value of the newly created row is always day 1 and year 2020.
That if I'm not mistaken to get what you mean.